# Object construction: test if this is instanceOf Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I've seen this test in the Object Constructors of vendor code:

```
function MyObject() {
  if (!(this instanceof MyObject)) return new MyObject;
  ...
}
```

My first inclination is that this test is used to prevent binding to another `this` value when calling the constructor. However, I wanted to check here incase there is something else I am missing. Can someone please explain the exact intent of this test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This test is to make sure that `MyObject` is always used as a constructor, namely:

```
var instance = new MyObject();
```

and never

```
var instance = MyObject();
```

which would lead to unwanted behavior of the code.

If someone accidentally uses `var instance = MyObject();` form then `this` inside of the function will be a global object (Window) and `instanceof` check would force proper constructor invocation in this case.

Some people however consider this pattern harmful because it fixes developers mistakes. I would personally throw an exception in this case instead of make careless developer fell like everything is okay.

Comment: Great answer! And 100% agree this should throw an exception rather than hold the careless dev's hand.

Comment: It should be added that this is mostly seen in nodejs modules where the value of a module's `export` can be many different things, not just an object constructor. With this said, documentation and throwing an exception is still preferential to "fixing" the code for the developer. I argue that implied construction will lead to a more egregious abuse of the code than what the test in question is trying to prevent.